# Reading Input - gets scanf - Newbie

Tags: c, eclipse, macos, scanf, gets

I am currently coding a program for an assignment involving customer orders... So far everything has been coded correct but now i have a problem when it comes to reading user input.. 2 lines are appearing on the screen without giving the user time to enter the order quantity.. This is because i am using scanf.. i tried making use of fflush(stdin) and get char() but none worked.. the following is the code which is giving me problems

```
puts("\nEnter Product Details\n");

puts("Product Name: ");

gets(newProduct.Name);

puts("ISBN: ");

gets(newProduct.ISBN);

puts("Description: ");

gets(newProduct.Description);

puts("Price: ");

scanf("%f",&newProduct.Price);

puts("Quantity in Stock: ");

scanf("%d",&newProduct.QuantityinStock);

printf("Supplier: ");

gets(newProduct.Supplier);

printf("Order Quantity: ");

scanf("%d",&newProduct.OrderQuantity);
```

Comment: Don't use `fflush(stdin);` anyway. It's undefined behaviour.

Comment: also we cannot make use of fgets : /

Comment: I'm not sure what the accepted way is, but you can change the `scanf` before `gets` to read a newline after the variable (`"%d\n"`).

Comment: the program is now running correct except for the last line.. Order Quantity appears on the screen but it returns swiftly to the main menu without giving the user time to input a value

Comment: OK SOLVED THE PROBLEM... DIDNT HAVE & FOR ONE OF THE SCANF

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using `getchar()` after `scanf()`

Comment: Enter Product Details

Product Name: 

BeatsHeadphones

ISBN: 

123143432432

Description: 

Music
Price: 
112
Quantity in Stock: 
10
Supplier: BEATS 
Order Quantity: 

 Main Menu

1.  Create Customer Record
2.  Modify Customer Record
3.  Create Product Record

Comment: Order Quantity appears on the screen but it returns swiftly to the main menu without giving the user time to input a value

Comment: OK SOLVED THE PROBLEM... DIDNT HAVE & FOR ONE OF THE SCANF